# No results from mysqli query result when using bind_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query that doesnt display results. i have tried many options but it doesnt work yet. Anyone with an idea why this is so. The code is below. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
$Week_ID = $teams->WeekID->CurrentValue;
$GK_1  = $teams->Keeper1->CurrentValue;

//Database info
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'soccer';

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT 'PName'=? ,'Player_price'=?, 'Player_points'=?, 'Total_points'=? FROM Keepers_points WHERE 'WeekNo'=? && 'PlayerNO'=?")) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $PName, $Player_price, $Player_points, $Total_points, $Week_ID, $GK_1 );

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

/* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($PName, $Player_price, $Player_points, $Total_points,$Week_ID, $GK_1 );

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo $Player_price;
    echo $Player_points;
    echo $Total_points;

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Either 1) *check* (and *report*) the result status of the relevant calls (e.g. execute/fetch) or 2) [enable exceptions](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) (Hint: the select is invalid, try `SELECT PName, ..` instead of the `SELECT x=? ..` wonkiness.)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Interesting. I never knew about that - my little world grew some :)

Comment: You can't bind columns and table names. Use actual column names.

Answer (score 0):

For printing the `result`, loop the query result.

```
$array = array();
while ($fetch = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $array[] = $fetch;
}
print_r($array);
```

Also your prepare statement is wrong

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT PName,Player_price, Player_points, Total_points FROM Keepers_points WHERE 'WeekNo'=? && 'PlayerNO'=?")) 
{
    $stmt->bind_param("dd", $Week_ID, $GK_1 );
```

Comment: I have corrected as above but still i get blank results.

Answer (score -1):

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $PName, $Player_price, $Player_points, $Total_points, $Week_ID, $GK_1 );
```

This line appears to be the culprit. Where is ssssss defined?
You are binding to an undefined parameter.

Comment: The code appears to be mysqli (not PDO), which uses "types" in a [single binding](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score -1):

this is how you need to do

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT PName ,Player_price, Player_points, Total_points FROM Keepers_points WHERE 'WeekNo'=? AND 'PlayerNO'=?")) {
        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param("dd", $Week_ID, $GK_1 );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($PName, $Player_price, $Player_points, $Total_points);

.....
```

Comment: see my edited answer,you have bind_result only columns that are in result

Comment: hello DOWNVOTER can you tell me the reason for the downvote??

Comment: that's simple. this query will never find anything useful

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#example-1762 (yeah i forgot to execute the query)